# Dynamic image in jsp

Tags: java, image, spring, spring-mvc

I try to put image generate in dynamic way using Spring mvc controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public String generateMik(final HttpServletResponse response){
...
BufferdImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
...

response.setContentType("image/png");
try {
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(buffer, "png", os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
...
}
```

And i show this picture in .jsp :

```
<img src="picture" id="picture">
```

All works fine, picture show in my browser, but i got a exception and i don't have any idea to resolve this problem in normal why (i don't wanna to catch this exception).

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:626)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:215)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:190)
...
```

And my question is: how i can generate dynamic picture in possibly simples way? I don't wanna to temporary save picture. Maybe put to model outputStream and show in somehow magic way in jsp?

Comment: *"All works fine, but i have error"*  Your definition of 'fine' is unusual to me.

Comment: just a thought what about just swapping out the image that exists at the url specified by the `src` attribute of the image tag? Wouldn't that techincally be dynamic? What if I need it to by related to the dynamic content you say? what about appending some type of identifier to the image name and dymamically generatign the url in the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to annotate the `@RequestMapping` method that is writing the image to the stream with `@ResponseBody` to tell Spring MVC not to try to find a view to use to render the response. You use `@ResponseBody` on any methods where you are handling writing to the output stream yourself.

Since your `@RequestMapping` method returns a `String`, Spring interprets the response value of your method as the name of the view it should use in rendering the response.

You are seeing the exception because you are writing (and closing) the response stream, and then Spring MVC tries to invoke a view class to write to the same response stream.

Answer (score 3):

i think this is due to you have return parameter in controller method which ask spring to forward request to particular view.

you should have return type as void.

```
public void generateMik(final HttpServletResponse response)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works fine for me:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/img", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void getImage(HttpServletResponse response)
{
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    response.setContentType("image/png");
    OutputStream out;
    try
    {
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(IndexController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

BUT, I'm 99,8% sure there's a smarter way to do it.

Comment: Btw, how did you calculate that 99.8%? :D